# read list items from sharepoint 2010 server to silverlight web application (cross-domain)

Tags: silverlight, web-services, sharepoint

on one server i have www with silverlight web application. In a diffrent place in the world is the secound server with sharepoint 2010 fondation. While client connects to www server, the silverloght web application goes to him, and then trying to read list elements from sharepoint. On client desktop comes Windows - login window, after client provide username and the password, application can read the list items.
Question:
how to login IN THIS CASE from silverlight application without user prompt.

part of my code (reads only list infromation):

```
    SilverlightApplication2.listsWebService.ListsSoapClient lws = new SilverlightApplication2.listsWebService.ListsSoapClient();


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lws.GetListCompleted += new EventHandler<listsWebService.GetListCompletedEventArgs>(lws_GetListCompleted);


        lws.GetListAsync("PagesContent");


    }

    void lws_GetListCompleted(object sender, listsWebService.GetListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        deltaValue.Text = e.Result.Value; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be very confusing when solving Silverlight auth in Sharepoint. I know this is possible when using Forms authentication, through web service called autentication.asmx.

With Windows authentication, I always used current logged user (which is SL default behavior).
I don't know if that can be changed from inside SL..

Here is one [article](http://rouslan.com/2009/03/20-steps-to-get-together-windows-authentication-silverlight-and-wcf-service/) that may help...

Sorry for such answer... :)